# java.sql.SQLException: Desbordamiento Numérico

Tags: java

Tengo el sgte codigo :

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());

List<Integer> numberData = new LinkedList<Integer>();
System.out.println("query ejecutada: ");

while (rs.next()) {
  numberData.add(rs.getInt("VALUE"));  => aqui da el error
}
```

La query me devuelve 2500 datos y el valor mas alto es 65000000000, creo que Integer su valor máximo es 4294967296, como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: `BigInteger` es la solución para números enteros grandes

Comment: en el resulset no se como obtener el biginteger, solo he visto bigdecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas simple es cambiar Integer por Long

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());

List<Long> numberData = new LinkedList<Long>();
System.out.println("query ejecutada: ");

while (rs.next()) {
  numberData.add(rs.getLong("VALUE")); 
}
```

Comment: ok gracias asi ha funcionado